# Applying cocoapods (Firebase) to extensions

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods

I tried directly adding target 'MyExtension' and some pods in Podfile, but that throws 'sharedApplication' is unavailable on iOS (app extension).

EDIT:

I have fixed the problem by adding:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = '$(inherited) GTM_BACKGROUND_UIAPPLICATION=0'
    end
  end
end
```

at the end of my Podfile, but this leads me to another basic question: where to call FIRApp.configure(), typically this is done in the AppDelegate, but custom keyboard extension does not have such a file. I assume putting it in viewDidLoad() is a bad idea (it works but seems iffy)?

Comment: Please post the Podfile contents and code that doesn't work

Comment: Please edit the post with the contents formatted as code

Comment: Sorry my apologies, have just updated main post.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

Added the below code to the end of my Podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] = '$(inherited) GTM_BACKGROUND_UIAPPLICATION=0'
    end
  end
end
```